# ASP.NET MVC 2 Issue - Dot in Route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm blanking and need a quick hand. Google has failed me. I'm working on replacing WCF/REST Starter Kit with ASP.NET MVC. I want to make the transition as painless as possible so I'm trying to create a route to match the following URL:

```
http://localhost/services/MyService.svc/UserInfo
```

I created the route in Global.asax.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "MyServiceDefault",
            "services/MyService.svc/{action}/{id}",
            new { 
                  controller = "MyService", 
                  action = "UserInfo", 
                  id = UrlParameter.Optional 
                }
        );
```

I soon realized that the request isn't even making it to my application because of the `.` in the `MyService.svc` part of the URL.

What am I missing to force the request to pass through to my application rather than being handled by the server as a static resource?

**Update**

I forgot to mention that I have also tried adding the following to Web.config to no avail:

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that searching for the correct combination of terms will eventually yield results. Phil Haack actually has a block post about this exact issue:

[Overriding a .svc Request With Routing](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/09/07/routing-and-build-providers.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20haacked%20%28you%27ve%20been%20HAACKED%29)

It turns out that for the *.svc extension, simply adding `<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />` to the Web.config isn't enough.

In one of the framework Web.config files, there is a build provider associated with the *.svc that takes over the request before it gets to .NET MVC (and fails since this isn't really a WCF service). Once you know that, it's easy enough to remove the build provider in your app's Web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    <buildProviders>
      <remove extension=".svc"/>            
    </buildProviders>
    ...
</system.web>
```

Comment: interesting. i will make a note of this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [RouteCollection.RouteExistingFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.routeexistingfiles.aspx) property. By default this is set to false. It could be that your service is located under the Services path in your project and this is causing the issue.

Comment: Even though I have no Services folder, I gave it a shot anyway. No luck. My app still doesn't get to handle the route.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs) tells how you can use different extensions with asp.net mvc application and still make them route to .NET framework. specifically pay attention to the part that starts with

```
This is done using a script named registermvc.wsf.
```