# ASP.NET MVC, email address as parameter breaking routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following actionresult:

> public ActionResult Confirmation(string emailAddress)

When I try to access it:

http://localhost:8080/Signup/Confirmation?emailAddress=test%40test.com

I get this:

```
The view 'test@test.com' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Signup/test@test.com.cshtml
~/Views/Signup/test@test.com.vbhtml
```

What gives why isn't it looking for the correct view? If I go to "/SignUp/" it correctly shows me the index, along with the other ActionResults working correctly. Why does an address break it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be http://localhost:8080/Signup/Confirmation/test%40test.com

Comment: I believe this is the typical "." issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732507/asp-net-mvc-2-issue-dot-in-route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried registering the route in the global.asax.cs?

Something like:

```
routes.Add("confirmation", 
    new Route("Signup/Confirmation/{email}", 
    new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Signup", action = "Confirmation", email = UrlParameter.Optional }), 
    new MvcRouteHandler())
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be passing that info in the URL anyway.

If this is kind of a "Confirmation" page from a signup, you could pass another identifier, e.g the UserId that has just been created, then fetch it from the repo.

E.g:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Signup(SignupViewModel model)
{
   //.. code to save.. etc

   return RedirectToAction("Confirmation", new { id = newUser.UserId });
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Confirmation(int id)
{
   var user = repo.FindById(id);
   // map to model, etc...
   return View(model);
}
```

So your URL would be (without a specialized route)

```
http://localhost:8080/Signup/Confirmation?id=123213
```

Putting user's email addresses in the URL is asking for them to be spammed.

Comment: I'm not sure how the user would be spammed.  How would a spammer be able to read any other users email address via URL when scraping the site?  I guess it's possible that a man in the middle could intercept the request and capture the url, but that seems like a very intensive way to get email addresses.

Comment: @Mystere Man - its possible. Let's not get into it, but generally speaking, always better *not* to pass this info around **where possible**, and it's certainly possible in this case. Adds no value to pass the email through in the URL.