# How to ASP.NET MVC3 Route to accept any type of file (Dot in URL)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, maproute

[ASP.NET MVC 2 Issue - Dot in Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732507/asp-net-mvc-2-issue-dot-in-route) gives an example to allow dot (.) in url and allow .svc file.

My question is, how to **allow any kind of file**, I tried:

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
<remove extension=".*"/>
```

Not working! What I want is: for any kind of URL (any chars) can processed by MVC3 Route(MapRoute).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution:

First: it will NOT cause security leak, if you visit `/web.config`, you will get

```
HTTP Error 404.8 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a path in the URL that contains a hiddenSegment section.
```

Unless you change the `hiddenSegment` of course.

here is the solution, at `web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="Static-Favicon" path="favicon.ico" verb="GET" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
        <add name="Static-Robot" path="robots.txt" verb="GET" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Static-Favicon and Static-Robot can be removed, if you like your MVC handle these two files as well.

Btw, you still need the `<remove extension=".svc" />` to handle svc file, and `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping` for special codes in url

Answer (score 0):

That's a very very very bad idea.  You want people to be able to download your web.config?  see your passwords?  download your database?  IIS and MVC deliberately block many kinds of extensions because not doing so is highly insecure.

Comment: It may open the door, but I can block the resource afterwards. My question is how, not why

Comment: Btw, there has a system.webServer/securityrequestFiltering for this secure purpose anyway

Comment: @EricYin - I was referring to what you said about being able to "allow any type of file".  If you understand why that's a bad idea, then perhaps you should not be asking that question, but rather how to allow the types of files you want.. that's a different story.

Comment: I already found solution, check below. Just a simple "catch-all" function, and when the project is clean, theres no file to steal anyway